# ts-node is changing tsconfig.json file

Tags: typescript, next.js, ts-node

I'm building a web application using Next.js and TypeScript. I have a custom `server.ts` file. Because of that, my development command is `ts-node server.ts`. Everything was working fine, until now :( Every time I try to run the command, my tsconfig.json file is changed.

I already tried the most basic solutions, such as removing the `node_modules` directory and running the `npm install` command again or reinstalling the whole Node.js. Unfortunately, nothing worked for me.

Here is my `tsconfig.json` file:

```
{
  "compileOnSave": false,
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es2017",
    "module": "esnext",
    "jsx": "preserve",
    "allowJs": true,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "noUnusedLocals": true,
    "noUnusedParameters": true,
    "removeComments": false,
    "preserveConstEnums": true,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "typeRoots": [
      "./types",
      "./node_modules/@types"
    ],
    "lib": [
      "dom",
      "esnext"
    ],
    "outDir": "dist/",
    "incremental": true,
    "strict": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "noEmit": true
  },
  "include": [
    "pages/*",
    "components/*",
    "server.ts"
  ],
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules",
    "**/*.spec.ts",
    "**/*.spec.tsx",
    "**/*.test.ts",
    "**/*.test.tsx",
    "jest.config.js",
    "jest.setup.js",
    "next.config.js"
  ]
}
```

And here is the message I'm getting after running `ts-node server.ts`:

```
The following changes are being made to your tsconfig.json file:
  - compilerOptions.strict to be suggested value: true (this can be changed)
  - compilerOptions.forceConsistentCasingInFileNames to be suggested value: true (this can be changed)
  - compilerOptions.esModuleInterop must be true (requirement for babel)
  - compilerOptions.module must be esnext (for dynamic import() support)
  - compilerOptions.resolveJsonModule must be true
  - compilerOptions.isolatedModules must be true (requirement for babel)
  - compilerOptions.noEmit must be true
```

Comment: Are you using `create-react-app`? This looks like some of their diagnostic messages when reverting custom settings to their opinionated defaults.

Comment: No, I'm just using Next.js with a custom server. Something like this: https://github.com/zeit/next.js/tree/canary/examples/custom-server-typescript

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I finally have found an issue. It looks like a automatic TypeScript setup was added in Next.js v8.1.1.canary.26 ([pull request](https://github.com/zeit/next.js/pull/7125)). However, it looks like it does not always work correctly. There is already an [issue](https://github.com/zeit/next.js/issues/7333) related to this new feature.